# Random jump within while() loop in PHP for MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing an example project for University and got a problem that I can't solve.
In general, the project is to create an automated pizza order system in PHP and MySQL on Apache. The system works through the following steps:
- Customer places order -> Baker receives order, proceeds -> Driver receives order at certain state, proceeds
- Customer can view order at all time through session

Now I hung up at the last step: The driver can see a page that has a table with the information that the baker worked with and passed on (all changes are on database side). The driver can only see a whole package (whenever all pizzas are marked as a certain status, also saved in DB).

For this, I have the following SQL statement

```
SELECT PizzaID, BestellungID, Adresse, PizzaName, Preis, Status FROM angebot, bestelltepizza, bestellung where bestellung.bestellungid = bestelltepizza.fbestellungid and angebot.PizzaName = bestelltepizza.fPizzaName and (select min(status) from bestelltepizza where bestellung.bestellungid = fbestellungid) >2 ORDER BY Status, BestellungID
```

Now, when I use `var_dump()` to get the `mysqli_num_rows()` output, I get no errors and the following output `int 26`. Compared to the database rows, it's the correct number. I fetch the sql:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($this->result)) {
    var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($this->result));
    var_dump($row);
    ...
}
```

Within the `while()` loop contains another query

```
$this->query = "SELECT fPizzaName FROM bestelltepizza WHERE fBestellungID = '$BestellID'";
var_dump($this->query);
$tmpResult = $this->_database->query($this->query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($tmpResult);
```

Now here is the problem, the `while()` loop leaves out a random `$BestellID` which can contain `x` rows of data. But when I count the output of `var_dump()` everything is correct. However, `var_dump($this->query);` is not showing the query statement for the specific jump, too.

Any ideas what this could be? Full link to pastebin below.

To not extend this question to the fullest, I uploaded the whole code to pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/u888CPLw

*Offtopic: Appreciate any help, thanks. If I failed clearing out my exact problem or if any questions pop up to my question, please comment and I will clarify. Thanks.*

Comment: You had me at 'pizza'. Then you lost me.

Comment: you're running nested queries where the inner query is using data from the outer query? You should be re-writing that as a single `join`ed query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($this->result)) { 
                        $count = mysqli_num_rows($tmpResult);

                        for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

                                $tmpVar = mysqli_fetch_array($this->result);
```

Ive snipped the code to show the problem

`$count` is based on `$tmpResult` you are then doing a fetch array on `$this->result` you should be doing it on `$tmpResult`

As Marc B says, Its a simple query to either inner join / left join on to the query. It would be better to use the join.

Comment: Yes, that did it. I've been working far to long today. Thank you very much!

Comment: What I don't get is, how would I write this query as I am using dynamic data to retrieve data from the new query? I cannot change table structures neither add or delete tables to the database (task restrictons)